# Latex Beamer - Media9 : Coloring the Mediabuttons & Playbutton

Tags: beamer, color, media9, video

My current code is the following

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction To AWS}
\hspace{-0.8cm}    
\includemedia[
 label=myVidPlayer,
 width=10cm,height=6cm,
 activate=pageopen,
 addresource=1.flv,
 addresource=2.flv,
 addresource=3.flv,
 addresource=4.flv,
 flashvars={
     source=1.flv %video to be shown at first
    &autoPlay=true
    &scaleMode=letterbox %useful, if videos are of different aspect ratio
 }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}


\mediabutton[mediacommand=myVidPlayer:setSource [(1.flv)]]{Alexa}
\mediabutton[mediacommand=myVidPlayer:setSource [(2.flv)]]{Philip Robot}
\mediabutton[mediacommand=myVidPlayer:setSource [(3.flv)]]{Sophia} 
\mediabutton[mediacommand=myVidPlayer:setSource [(4.flv)]]{Bot Simulation}


\end{frame}
```

1) How can I color the mediabuttons ?

The way they are now is kinda disturbing as it looks all connected together since its all white colored. Can I make them fancier or color them?

2) Can I add a play and a pause button as well?

3) Can I center the video ?

Current View:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: See the example on p. 23 of the media9 documentation. It has a Play/Pause button and uses `\fbox` to produce a button look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How can I color the mediabuttons ?

You can replace "Alexa" with whatever commands you like to create coloured buttons, for example with `\colorbox{<color>}{<text>}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction To AWS}
\hspace{-0.8cm}    
\includemedia[
 label=myVidPlayer,
 width=10cm,height=6cm,
 activate=pageopen,
 addresource=video01.flv,
 flashvars={
     source=video01.flv %video to be shown at first
    &autoPlay=true
    &scaleMode=letterbox %useful, if videos are of different aspect ratio
 }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\mediabutton[mediacommand=myVidPlayer:setSource [(video01.flv)]]{\colorbox{red}{\strut Alexa}}


\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

> 2. Can I center the video?

You could use `\hfill` before and after the video

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction To AWS}
{
\hfill
\includemedia[
 label=myVidPlayer,
 width=10cm,height=6cm,
 activate=pageopen,
 addresource=video01.flv,
 flashvars={
     source=video01.flv %video to be shown at first
    &autoPlay=true
    &scaleMode=letterbox %useful, if videos are of different aspect ratio
 }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\hfill
}

\mediabutton[mediacommand=myVidPlayer:setSource [(video01.flv)]]{Alexa}


\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: An additional `\strut` in the text argument of the `\colorbox` could be useful for all boxes to have the same height and depth.